# WooCommerce Shortcode For "Order Again" Customer's Last Order

Tags: woocommerce

I'm fairly new with this, but I am learning. I am trying to create a shortcode which can be inserted anywhere on the site, allowing the customer to order their previous order again.

In other words, I need to enable the customer to "order again" their last order. Main problem is, when I try this, the site goes blank (white screen).

Any ideas what's wrong here?

```
add_shortcode( 'order_again', 'matt_order_again' );
function matt_order_again( $order ) {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

     $user_id = get_current_user_id();
     $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );
     $last_order = $customer->get_last_order();

    if ( $last_order->has_status( 'completed' ) ) {
        $actions['order-again'] = array(
            'url' => wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( 'order_again', $order->get_id(), wc_get_cart_url() ), 'woocommerce-order_again' ),
            'name' => __( 'Order again', 'woocommerce' ),
        );
    }
    return $actions;
  }
}
```

I have tried adding the global variable for WC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
add_shortcode( 'order_again', 'matt_order_again' );
function matt_order_again( $order ) {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

     $user_id = get_current_user_id();
     $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );
     $last_order = $customer->get_last_order();

   
    if ( $last_order->has_status( 'completed' ) ) {
        $actions['order-again'] = array(
            'url' => wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( 'order_again', $last_order->get_id(), wc_get_cart_url() ), 'woocommerce-order_again' ),
            'name' => __( 'Order again', 'woocommerce' ),
        );
    }
    return $actions;
  }
}
```

Or if you want to return a button with url for order again using shorcode use this code (edited).

```
add_shortcode('order_again', 'matt_order_again');
function matt_order_again($order)
{

    if (is_user_logged_in()) {

        global $woocommerce;
        ob_start();
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $customer = new WC_Customer($user_id);
        $last_order = $customer->get_last_order();

         if(!$last_order){
             return;
          }
        if ($last_order->has_status('completed')) {

            $url = wp_nonce_url(add_query_arg('order_again', $last_order->get_id(), wc_get_cart_url()), 'woocommerce-order_again');
            echo '<a href="' . $url . '">' . __('Order Again', 'woocomerce') . '</a>';
        }

        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $contents;
    }
    
}
```